# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first on Dialog Box

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have a method that is displaying a custom Dialog Box

```
fun showDialog(){

val resultsDialog = Dialog(this)

resultsDialog.setContentView(dialogBinding.root)
dialogBinding.tvDialogCategory.text = CategoryType.HISTORY.name

dialogBinding.tvDialogSetMeetMinimumCriteria.text =displayResultString

resultsDialog.create()

resultsDialog.show()
}
```

However, when I call this method again after making some validations in my Activity code,

```
myButton.setOnClickListener{
  //some validation code here
  showDialog()
 

}
```

I'm getting the error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

I've tried various ways to solve this issue but not able to do so. How can I solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you are reusing the same `dialogBinding.root`, rather than creating a new one for each new dialog you want to show. Why is your dialog and the dialog's view not 1:1?

Comment: Yes I'm using the same binding object. I set it up in the Activity's onCreate() method. How do I get around this issue?

Comment: Hey thanks Ian I moved the resultsDialog = Dialog(this) in the onCreate(). Created a new instance of dialogBinding and it worked like a charm. You saved my Cake. I spent a whole lotta time trying to figure out what the issue was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put result dialog into global variable

```
class YourActivity : BaseActivity(){  
  lateinit var resultsDialog
```

Then Breakdown your show dialog into 2 method, one for initialize the dialog, the other for showing the dialog

```
fun initDialog(){
  resultsDialog = Dialog(this)
  resultsDialog.setContentView(dialogBinding.root)
  dialogBinding.tvDialogCategory.text = CategoryType.HISTORY.name
  dialogBinding.tvDialogSetMeetMinimumCriteria.text =displayResultString
  resultsDialog.create()
}

fun showDialog(){
  resultsDialog.show()
}
```

after that, call initDialog() only once on your oncreate method and call your showDialog() on myButton clicklistener

Comment: I almost ended up doing the same thing. Though I created my Dialog instance in the onCreate() and created a new binding instance like 
ianhanniballake mentioned in the previous comment,  along with setContentView() in the showDialog() method. It worked for me then.